# JQuery - Convert array of 'HTMLDivElement' objects to string

Tags: jquery, find, each

I filter elements on a page and then check how many items are displayed and if there's less than a certain amount I want to load more items using $.get().

I am using the isotope plugin which requires the new items to be a string, but I can only seem to get HTMLDivElement objects.  How do I convert this to a string?

```
                var $container = $('#container'),
                        filters = {};
                $container.isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.element',
                });

                function loadMoreItems(getQuery) {
                    var newItems = [];
                    $.get(getQuery, null, function(data) {
                        container = $($container, data).eq(0);
                        if (0 === container.length) {
                            // incase the element is a root element (body > element),
                            // try to filter it
                            container = $(data).filter($container).eq(0);
                        }

                        if (container) {
                            container.find('.element').each(function() {
                                newItems.push(this);
                            });
                        }

                        alert(newItems);  //what to do to get this as a string??


                    }, 'html');
                     $container.isotope('insert', newItems, true);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with isotope, but if you need the html with all elements in one string you can simply to `$(elements).html()` or if you need an array with each element as a string you can do

```
var transformElements = [];
$.each($(elements), function(index, value){
    transformElements.push($(value).html());
})
```

In your particular case you can do:

```
var newItems = "";
if (container) {
    newItems = container.find('.element').html();
}
```

which will create a single string with the html from all the elements.

Comment: thanks for the response, however, how do I write this exactly?  I have tried various ways to fit this into my code but nothing seems to work.  I simply need a long string, not an array.  I have tried doing this.html() instead of newItems.push(this); but I get an error